# Which option to choose in Redwolf TWRP Recovery for OTA update support?

Tags: twrp, ota-update, redmi-note-4

I recently flashed the redwolf twrp recovery on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 (Snapdragon variant; code name - mido) which runs on MIUI10 (beta) based on Android 7.0 Nougat.

Now the reason behind the flashing is the fact that it supports the incremental OTA update.

But I have a problem in understanding which option I should choose to support the OTA updates. In fact, the redwolf twrp recovery I flashed is the latest build and there is no mention on the internet which option I should tick. Here is the image of the page:

[image: IMG:]

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Did you search on XDA thread for the recovery. Cursory search indicates you need to select the unselected option too

Comment: Here is a guide on XDA-Dev - https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-4/how-to/red-wolf-install-twrp-root-device-t3708337 But buddy i am sure about redwolf ota working with miui 10 beta, still googling, i'll update when i figure this out. Good luck.